# RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded. In a expansion Tile

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an expansion tile which I like that when it expands to show my widgets in a row and make its size dynamic to the children's size, so I tried this:

```dart
ExpansionTile(
        maintainState: true,
        tilePadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        title: Text(
          '${color.id}',
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .subtitle1
              .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
        childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        children: [
         
          Flexible(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ...colors.types.map<Widget>(
                          (item) {
                        return Expanded(
                            child: ListView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              children: [
                                ...item.prices.map<Widget>((size) {
                                  return Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Column(
                                        children: [
                                          MyWidget(
                                              color: color,
                                              size: size
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  );
                                }),
                              ],
                            )
                        );
                      }
                  ),
                ],
              )
          )
        ]
      );
```

But throws this error:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

If I put a Container instead of a Flexible with MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, it shows the widgets fine but fill the entire screen, what I want is the container with the size necessary to show the children. What I have to do?

Comment: Did u try Wrap? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Comment: I tried Wrap instead of Flexible and it throws: "Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / x. Figure out how much space you need and allocate it in a container's height. That container can contain a scrollable list but will prevent renderflex errors.